# How to fix error in android sdk - java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: android, eclipse

Soon as I open eclipse, I get following error on popup:

```
Unknown exception in parseSdkContent.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

If I close this popup I get another popup saying the following:

```
A stack overflow error has occurred.
you are recommended to exit the workbench.
subsequent errors may happen and may terminate the workbench without warning.
see the .log file for more details.
```

So than I checked my .log file and it had a following error:

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2015-05-13 22:56:25.701
!MESSAGE Unknown exception in parseSdkContent.
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.ProjectState.buildFullLibraryDependencies(ProjectState.java:682)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.ProjectState.buildFullLibraryDependencies(ProjectState.java:691)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.ProjectState.buildFullLibraryDependencies(ProjectState.java:691)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.ProjectState.buildFullLibraryDependencies(ProjectState.java:691)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.ProjectState.buildFullLibraryDependencies(ProjectState.java:691)
```

I already tried the following 5 things:

1) Re-install eclipse and reset my phone

2) Update android SDK Manager

3) Update ADT

4) Delete my .android folder

5) Use 'task manager' to end 'adb'. than I restart my adb using cmd.

But nothing is seem to be working. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to trace down memory leaks. We use canaryleaks in order to monitor objects that might cause problems in the future.

Take a look at this post, this might help you.

https://corner.squareup.com/2015/05/leak-canary.html